# Ubuntu 14.04: tomcat7 permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, permissions

I have been running a tomcat7 application on my Ubuntu machine and everything worked fine. Since some time, probably after a system update, I'm getting strange permission denied errors and I'm quite at puzzled here.

The tomcat7 application "ChemDB" is deployed and basically it works fine. I'm using an  hsqldb database accessing files on disk, and that's where the problem starts. When the application tries to read the database, I get the following error:

```
JavaException: java.sql.SQLException: The database is already in use by another process: 
org.hsqldb.persist.NIOLockFile@61c4c3b4[file =/home/leo/ChemDB/chemdb.hsql.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, fl =null]: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/leo/ChemDB/chemdb.hsql.lck (Permission denied)
```

Folder permissions are:

```
leo@lenovo2:~/ChemDB$ pwd
/home/leo/ChemDB
leo@lenovo2:~/ChemDB$ ll
drwxrwxrwx  2 tomcat7 tomcat7  4096 Jan 19 13:57 ./
drwx------ 46 leo     leo      4096 Jan 19 14:08 ../
-rw-rw-rw-  1 tomcat7 tomcat7    51 Jan  9  2014 chemdb.hsql.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 tomcat7 tomcat7   419 Jan  9  2014 chemdb.hsql.properties
-rw-rw-rw-  1 tomcat7 tomcat7 18427 Jan  9  2014 chemdb.hsql.script
```

Looks to me as if everything is writable by tomcat7.

The tomcat instance runs as user "tomcat7":

```
leo@lenovo2:~/ChemDB$ ps aux | grep "tomcat"
tomcat7  10116  0.5  2.6 387396 108940 ?       Sl   13:53   0:14 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I don't find any additional information in the Tomcat log files.

Strange: If I create the file "chemdb.hsqldb.lck" manually, the error message still shows "exists=false".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The tomcat user does not have permission to access your home directory, try moving to another directory outside the home (Eg: /opt/database/).

Comment: Thanks. I found that I needed to make /home/leo read- and executable. It's as simple as that... I guess I have to re-educate myself on Linux permissions ;-)